# WordPress WooCommerce Shipping costs will be calculated once you have provided your address WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Custom Shipping Method, from which the customer has to choose by themselves.
However when you go on the cart or checkout page it only says
“Shipping costs will be calculated once you have provided your address.”

To work around it I have tried to tick “enable the shipping calculator on the cart page” under “shipping options” but failed. Even the "Calculate Shipping" link is also not working.  I have searched many tuts on shipping method but no success.

After doing few modification, now i get following error:

> There are no shipping methods available. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below step..

1. Go to Woo-commerce setting select "Sell to all contries"  in Selling location(s)
2. Then after select "Ship to all countries you sell to" in Shipping location(s)
3. After setting remove specific country from the "Shipping zones > Your zone" and Set shipping anywhere.

After all set up please check on cart page.

Thank you.